# Anomalies and discontinuities in StreamPlot

Tags: plotting

```
 s1 = StreamPlot[{1, 2*x*y^2}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}];
 s2 = Plot[1/(4 - x^2), {x, -3, 3}, PlotStyle -> Red];
 Show[s1, s2]
```

[image]

In this problem the solution is not valid at x=2,-2,,,,but by showing the graph of solution and `StreamPlot` at the same time I can't find any interpretation about the solution....

Comment: See [How to copy code from Mathematica so it looks good on this site](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1584/how-to-copy-code-from-mathematica-so-it-looks-good-on-this-site) and [Hints and help on using the site efficiently](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1479/hints-and-help-on-using-the-site-efficiently) and [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) and read the [FAQ](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help)

Comment: I am not able to understand the question. You talk about a solution but not showing any equations to be solved. Try to re-formulate the question to make it clear what you are seeking.

Comment: @Jack, I believe the OP is looking at the ODE $y^\prime=2xy^2$; the function being plotted is then one particular solution.

Comment: Maybe what you're asking about is this: get rid of the singularities by adding `Exclusions -> {-2, 2}` to `s2`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`StreamPoints`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StreamPoints.html) to highlight the particular solution you are interested in, and check the results.

```
s1 = StreamPlot[{1, 2*x*y^2}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
   StreamPoints -> {{{{0, 1/4}, Red}, {{2.5, -1/2.25}, Red}, {{-2.5, -1/2.25}, Red},
      Automatic}}];
s2 = Plot[1/(4 - x^2), {x, -3, 3}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Opacity[0.3], Red, Thickness[0.02]}, PlotRange -> 3, 
   Exclusions -> 4 - x^2 == 0];
Show[s1, s2]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 0):

What's happening is that the solution is going to -Infinity near -2 and then coming back from +Infinity. By changing the scales this becomes a little more clear:

```
s1 = StreamPlot[{1, 2*x*y^2}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}];
s2 = Plot[1/(4 - x^2), {x, -3, 3}, PlotStyle -> Red, 
   PlotRange -> {-10, 10}];
Show[s2, s1]
```

[image]

Comment: Brother Can you please tell me actually why do we use StreamPlot in mathematica ....Since we have the solution and we can easily plot it,,,but what is the necessity for StreamPlot.....Thnx in advance

Comment: Differential equations have may solutions, depending on the starting value(s). So the red solution is just one possibility. The streamplot shows many others.